# How to include dynamic configmap and secrets in helmfile

Tags: helmfile

I am using helmfile to deploy multiple sub-charts using `helmfile sync -e env` command.

I am having the configmap and secretes which I need to load based on the environment.

Is there a way to load configmap and secretes based on the environment in the helmfile.

I tried to add in the

**dev-configmap.yaml**

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
        name: backend
        namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
    data:
        NODE_ENV: {{ .Values.env }}
```

**In helmfile.yaml**

```
environments:
    envDefaults: &envDefaults
        values:
            - ./values/{{ .Environment.Name }}.yaml
            - kubeContext: ''
              namespace: '{{ .Environment.Name }}'
    dev:
        <<: *envDefaults
        secrets:
            - ./config/secrets/dev.yaml
            - ./config/configmap/dev.yaml
```

Is there a way to import configmap and secrets (Not encrypted) YAML dynamically based on the environment in helmfile?

Comment: I'd normally expect Helmfile to manage entire Helm charts and not individual Kubernetes resources.  What's in the two `dev.yaml` files?